# Redirect on form's submission with window.location.href

Tags: html, forms

Trying out this simple code, I am amazed it didn't work, here we go :

```
<form method="get" action="" >
    <input type="submit" value="validate" onclick="redirect(); alertIt(); "/>
</form>
<script>
    function redirect(){
       window.location.href = "test.html" ;
    }
</script>
<script>
function alertIt(){
   alert("redirect");
}
</script>
```

The code is just supposed to redirect to "test.html" on click of the submit button, which it fails to do. On the other hand : alertIt() works fine... My question is the following : does event handeling into a form have some special rules I should know about ?

Comment: Try changing `type="submit"` to `type="button"`

Comment: Or just use a `<button type='button'>` if all you want is something clickable that executes custom JS.

Comment: But what if I want to keep the type as submit ? Why will it not work ?

Comment: @Gloserio Why do you want to keep the type as submit when the button clearly isn't submitting the form? If you want a button that goes to another page, use an `<a>` around a `<button>`.

Comment: @millimoose : I plan to submit the form.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to return false if you want the form not to submit anyway.

```
function redirect(){
       window.location.href = "test.html" ;
}
```

Should be

```
function redirect(){
    window.location.href = "test.html" ;
    return false;
}
```

You should also hook on the `submit` event and not the click event preferably, and return in the handler.

```
onclick="return redirect(); alertIt(); "
```

Would work (but not alert)

Optimally, what you'd want to do is add an id to the form for example myForm and attach an event to it.

```
document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit",function(){
    alertIt();
    return redirect(); 
},false);
```

Comment: I'd also consider handling the form's `onsubmit` instead of the button's `onclick` to make it clear which action you're trying to prevent.

Comment: @millimoose You are completely correct. Honesty I'd use un-obtrustive JavaScript. Doing `addEventListener('submit',redirect,false)` would probably be best.

Comment: Since these functions are called from within an anonymous function, the return values won't matter.

Comment: @millimoose : tried that as well, same result. It appears it's the submit type that's nasty...

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - Yes, because you added the *return* to the `onclick` attribute as well.  Your answer didn't state that.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum : problem is... I want the form to submit, actually, what I want is submit then redirect, any advice on that ?

Comment: @Gloserio I don't understand what you mean by "submit to redirect", if you want to submit to another page you can set the `action` attribute of the form, for example `<form action='test.html'>`

Comment: @Gloserio - Either your form submits to the URL defined in the `action` property, or it runs some script which cancels the submission.  You can't have both.  You can, however, submit the form to a page that then issues a 302 redirect to another page.

Comment: @Gloserio Alternately, you could consider doing the submit over AJAX and then doing whatever redirect you want in the browser. (Although it's "neater" to handle this server-side unless you're making an app with a client-side controller.)

Comment: What I was actually hoping for is submit the form and after submitting it be redirected. The reason for it is that I need to parse the query part of the URL, after which I wouldn't mind being redirected to a test.html page just for convenience. I knew about action, but I was puzzeled at discovering  redirecting with window.location.href won't work from inside a form ; This is of course unorthodox usage of form submission but I was kind of juggeling with the code...

Comment: @Gloserio you can create an AJAX request to the page you want to submit to and then redirect to wherever.

Comment: @millimoose : there are alternatives, yes. I just wanted to understand why this particular code isn't functionning, any explanation ?

Comment: @Gloserio yeah, read my answer. You have to return false if you want the submit not to happen. You can't submit _and_ redirect. After all you're making an HTTP request that isn't AJAX. You can add `target="_black"` as an attribute to the form but that's a poor solution.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum : ok, got it now ;) thanks guys, appreciate it a lot !

Answer (score 1):

You can use `location.replace()` too. Following link explains JavaScript location with working example.

http://www.codecandle.com/Articles/450/Javascript/Browser-Objects/Javascript-Location/codedetail.aspx

may help you.

Comment: Just tried it, didn't work. It's like @BenjaminGruenbaum said : submitting and redirecting from a form are pretty incompatible unless you pass by the action attribute. 
But thanks for the suggestion though, nice of you.